# Lock camera after device admin deprecation

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an app that uses the Device Admin prev. to disable\enable the camera,

From my understanding this will be deprecated in android 10..

The question is will it still work on android P\Q considering I will still be on

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

or do I need to do something else for it to happen ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation#timelines)

> Device admin is marked deprecated for enterprise use through updates
>   to documentation. **Existing functionality continues to work for
>   applications targeting the API level 28, though its use is
>   discouraged**.

So, `targetSdkVersion 26` will work for you. But There may be issue from Play Store side. Not sure if they will check your application and reject.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to: [Device administration preview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin)

Starting with Android 9 admin policies will be deprecated.
According to: [Device admin deprecation](https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation) `USES_POLICY_DISABLE_CAMERA` will also be deprecated.

**I would better suggest you to see the migration options.**
Refer [Device admin deprecation](https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation) to see the migration options.